# Unit Test Page Model that uses UrlHelper

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-routing, razor-pages, .net-5

I am trying to unit test a razor page model method that uses `UrlHelper`.

The current behavior is that I get this exception:

`System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find an IRouter associated with the ActionContext. If your application is using endpoint routing then you can get a IUrlHelperFactory with dependency injection and use it to create a UrlHelper, or use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator.`

I am pretty new to this and I've spent a couple hours trying to figure how to get past this blocker by using the exception message.

The page model code looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
  //some code

  var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
  var callbackUrl = await BuildNeededLink(user);

  //some more code 
}

public async Task<string> BuildNeededLink(User user)
{
   var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

   code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

   return Url.Page
   (
     pageName: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
     pageHandler: null,
     values: new { area = "Identity", code },
     protocol: Request.Scheme
   );
}
```

Thanks.